Почему батч-нормализация в CNN работает по-другому?
В полносвязном слое происходит усреднение по объектам в батче.
В сверточном слое происходит усреднение по объектам в батче + усреднение по ширине и высоте картинки.
мне причина такого усреднения не очень понятна. Я полазил по английскому SO с таким же вопросом, но так и не смог понять, видимо, из-за языкового порога и немного различающихся терминов. пример :

because filter weights are shared across the input image


свёртка - одинаковая по всей картинке, о чём вам и говорит эта цитата

@Eskri ааа, вот теперь действительно понятно, спасибо. Вот тут как раз не понял выражение shared across, отсюда и было непонимание))
